# "Delete last word" works wrongly on zsh

Tags: zsh

On zsh, for example, operating on command line string `abc -def`:

- pressing `Ctrl + W` once to delete word once, `def` gets deleted and `abc -` remain
- pressing twice, `abc -` is gone.

What I'm hoping is (and this is what I'm getting on bash):

- pressing `Ctrl + W` once, `-def` gets deleted and `abc` remains.
- pressing twice, `abc` is gone as well.

Any way to get the desired behavior? Thanks!

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250690/how-to-configure-ctrlw-as-delete-word-in-zsh

Comment: Thank you @oguzismail. Setting `WORDCHARS` worked!